# SSIS XML Parsing Error with Parent/Child Elements with Same Name

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

I am having a problem parsing an XML file to MS SQL staging tables via SSIS due to the XSD file structure which I may not change.  Here is the XSD format:

```html
<xs:element name="syndromes">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="syndrome" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="syndromeid" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="uniqueid" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="syndrome" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="syndromespec" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have mapped all of my table and setup an SSIS package to import the data from the XML into some staging tables.  When I run the SSIS package it immediately fails and states the following:

[ABC_TEST_XML [2822]] Error: The ABC_TEST_XML was unable to process the XML data. The element "syndrome" cannot contain a child element. Content model is text only.

After doing some research, it looks as though SSIS can't handle the two elements "syndrome" with the same name.  The XSD is able to allow me to setup all of my column mappings so I do not understand why when parsing the XML file it fails.  Is there any work around?  Is there a way to transform the data in the file prior to parsing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am not allowed to change the XSD nor am I allowed to instruct the sender of the data to change the source XML file.  I have to be able to parse the data as it is against the existing XSD.

Comment: Please edit your post and share the following: (1) your input XML, (2) Complete XSD (not just a fragment of it).

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is very similar:
[The Component "XML Source" Was unable to process the XML data. ambiguous complextype definition. The Element '%' has multiple members named '%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377361/the-component-xml-source-was-unable-to-process-the-xml-data-ambiguous-complex)

I've never used MQ SQL's SSIS but it seems fairly obvious that SSIS has some serious limitations when it comes to structured XML. I suggest that you take the same approach as VinayK in the other thread - use XSL to change the XML into something that SSIS will accept.